Query Returns Invalid error on Column Already Exists?
I want to Group BY Date and Payment and branch name and code
I don't know why this SQL query return this error:

Column 'FactSalesTable.SalesTotal' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either     an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT 
    FactSalesTable.Date,
    FactSalesTable.PaymentID,
    Branch.* ,
    SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) AS TotalSales,
    AVG (FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) AS AvgSales,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) /AVG(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) > 1 THEN 'Above Avg' 
        WHEN SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch.BCode)/AVG(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) = 1 THEN 'Avg'
        ELSE 'Below Avg'
    END AS SalesResult
FROM Branch
LEFT JOIN FactSalesTable ON Branch.BCode = FactSalesTable.BCode
WHERE FactSalesTable.SalesTotal > 0 AND Branch.BCode = 1021
GROUP BY FactSalesTable.Date, Branch.BranchName, Branch.BCode, FactSalesTable.PaymentID
ORDER BY FactSalesTable.Date DESC

I want to show the total sales by date like



date
BCode
total sales
avg




2023-04-30
1021
4333
5050


2022-04-30
1021
6392
5050


2022-04-29
1021
3544
5050


2022-04-29
1021
2300
5050



This is a snip of the query without the group by


Because of your windowed aggregates. Consumable sample data (not images) and expected results will help us help you.

We don't post images of sample data or results here. It makes it much less likely you'll get an answer, because then we have to retype all the data by hand to set up a test fiddle, and aint nobody got time for that.

Put the query except the AVG thing in a subquery and then you're free to average to your heart contents. Agree with previous speakers though, posting output of your query is pointless (and even worse when it's in image form), what helps is input and expected output

my mistake , I have added sample data

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/W7JahRBD

You are aggregating at two levels:

An ordinary aggregation SUM(SalesTotal) for each branch & payment as defined by the GROUP BY.
A windowed aggregation SUM(...) OVER(...) and AVG(...) OVER(...) across all payments per branch as defined by the OVER(,,,) window specifier.

Your problem is that your windowed aggregation functions are attempting to access the raw data, when I believe you intend to sum and average the grouped-by values. Instead of AVG(SalesTotal) OVER(...), I believe you need AVG(SUM(SalesTotal)) OVER(...).  However, for the SUM() cases in the SalesResult calculatiion, I believe that you want just the plain (non-windowed) branch & payment sum SUM(SalesTotal), not the sum of sums at the branch level.
Also, sinve you have constrained FactSalesTable.SalesTotal > 0, the FactSalesTable rows must be present and your LEFT JOIN is effectively an INNER JOIN.
The following should be closer to what you are trying to achieve.
SELECT 
    FactSalesTable.Date,
    FactSalesTable.PaymentID,
    Branch.* ,
    SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal) AS TotalSales,
    AVG (SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal)) OVER(PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) as AvgSales ,
    case 
        when SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal)
             / AVG(SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal)) OVER(PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) > 1
             THEN 'Above Avg' 
        when SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal)
             / AVG(SUM(FactSalesTable.SalesTotal)) OVER(PARTITION BY Branch.BCode) = 1
            THEN 'Avg'
        else 'Below Avg'
    end as SalesResult
FROM Branch
LEFT JOIN FactSalesTable  ON Branch.BCode = FactSalesTable.BCode
WHERE FactSalesTable.SalesTotal > 0 and Branch.BCode = 1021
Group BY FactSalesTable.Date,Branch.BranchName ,Branch.BCode,FactSalesTable.PaymentID
ORDER BY FactSalesTable.Date DESC

Results:



Date
PaymentID
BCode
BranchName
TotalSales
AvgSales
SalesResult




2022-04-30
57517
1021
Main Branch
19939.00
16223.000000
Above Avg


2022-04-30
57519
1021
Main Branch
12507.00
16223.000000
Below Avg



See this db<>fiddle. (Thanks to Bart McEndree for the test data setup.)
There are likely ways to further restructure the query to limit redundant expressions and improve readability, such as my moving the initial grouping logic to a subquery or CTE, and performing the windowed operations in the final/outer query. Another might be to wrap all payment logic up in a CROSS APPLY.

It Worked , but what I was looking for is a group by date and sum of all payment method  "total daily sales " to check it against the average
so I removed PaymantID . thank you

@Ahmed - I thought that grouping by PaymentID seemed suspicous. Glad you figured that out. Another thought: If FactSalesTable.Date is a date/time column, but you only want to group by date, you may need to use a cast or conversion like CONVERT(DATE, FactSalesTable.Date) in both the group-by, select-list, and order-by..
